# Making the data longer based on pre-specified condition using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot

I have this df

```
structure(list(study_id = structure(c(1, 3, 4), label = "Subject Study ID"), 
    creatinine1 = structure(c(82, 140, 88), label = "Baseline Creatinine"), 
    creatinine2 = structure(c(90, 122, 125), label = "Creatinie level: 3 months"), 
    egfr1 = structure(c(85, 42, 75), label = "Baseline eGFR "), 
    egfr2 = structure(c(73, 50, 50), label = "eGFR levels : 3 months"), 
    treat = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Active", "Placebo"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I want to make it longer and making a new column `"biomarker"` and if the column name in the original df end with `1`, its value goes to a new column `baseline` and if it ends with `2`, the value goes to `three_months` column. The prefix of these columns goes into the `biomarker`. I want the final df to look like this

```
structure(list(study_id = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4), biomarkers = c("Creatinine", 
"eGFR", "Creatinine", "eGFR", "Creatinine", "eGFR"), baseline = c(82, 
85, 140, 42, 88, 75), thre_months = c(90, 73, 122, 50, 125, 50
), treat = c("active", "active", "placebo", "placebo", "active", 
"active")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` and then rename columns:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(creatinine1:egfr2,
               names_to = c("biomarkers", ".value"),
               names_sep = "(?=\\d)") %>%
  rename(baseline = `1`, three_months = `2`)

# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   study_id treat   biomarkers baseline three_months
#      <dbl> <fct>   <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1        1 Active  creatinine       82           90
# 2        1 Active  egfr             85           73
# 3        3 Placebo creatinine      140          122
# 4        3 Placebo egfr             42           50
# 5        4 Placebo creatinine       88          125
# 6        4 Placebo egfr             75           50
```

---

###### Update

An alternative transformation according to the comment:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(creatinine1:egfr2,
               names_to = c(".value", "time_point"),
               names_sep = "(?=\\d)") %>%
  mutate(time_point = case_match(time_point, "1" ~ "baseline", "2" ~ "three_months"))

# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   study_id treat   time_point   creatinine  egfr
#      <dbl> <fct>   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>
# 1        1 Active  baseline             82    85
# 2        1 Active  three_months         90    73
# 3        3 Placebo baseline            140    42
# 4        3 Placebo three_months        122    50
# 5        4 Placebo baseline             88    75
# 6        4 Placebo three_months        125    50
```

Comment: structure(list(study_id = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4), time_point = c("Baseline", 
"three_months", "Baseline", "three_months", "Baseline", "three_months"
), creatinine = c(82, 90, 140, 122, 88, 125), eGFR = c(85, 73, 
42, 50, 75, 50), treat = c("active", "active", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

Comment: Can I transform it that original df to the above in the comment?